# Visual Studio 2022 Bugs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

So in the old VS programs I could place objects in design view and have them render in program execution. I download the new VS 2022 and this is what I get. Any assistance?

[image: Before Render]

[image: After execution]

Clearly the program seems significantly more sophisticated but Im dying here, what could I be doing wrong?

I thought the issue may have to do with the screen scaling but it isnt, that also doesnt work but even with scaling the button text would appear. Honestly not sure.

Comment: Visual not Visua sorry

Comment: I don't think you need any reputation to edit the title of your question.  Could be wrong.

Comment: If you're going to edit it, I would suggest a title more descriptive of the actual problem.

Comment: Is this a MDI child of GWStore?

Comment: For your button to have moved like that, I would check its Anchor property. It should have Left and Top selected. It looks like it has Right and Bottom selected.

Comment: Does the same thing happen in a new project? Sometimes specific projects can become corrupted and it's hard to impossible to determine exactly how. This is an example of why everyone should use source control, as you can always roll back to a known good state.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. In this case, step-by-step instructions on what you're doing would be beneficial.

Comment: Try adjusting your system's display scaling to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file I was using was corrupted somehow as –
jmcilhinney stated. All good now, thank you.